Inserting data dynamically using python
How can I insert a dynamic data to a my SQL database's table using Python, like taking an input and inserting it to a table using a function, or a function to add an object's attributes to the table?
(I am using MySQL workbench btw)
I didn't try anything because I have no idea how to do it.
